# Trying to edit post: Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>[^/]+)/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to be able to edit the question with an  tag which references my edit_post function in my views.py. I think the issue is because I haven't passed in the context into the right view for it to be displayed but I am not sure how to fix it. Getting this error - Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P[^/]+)/edit/(?P[0-9]+)$']

**Views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def dashboard(request, *args, **kwargs):

    username = request.user.username

    filtered_questions = Question.objects.filter(user_id=username)

    context = {
    'filtered_questions': filtered_questions,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', context)

def edit_post(request, pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if rerquest.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            question.user = request.user
        
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = QuestionForm(instance=question) 
    else:
        form = QuestionForm(instance=question)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'question': question,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/edit_question.html', context)
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<username>', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('<username>/upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('<username>/edit/<int:pk>', views.edit_post, name='edit')
]
```

**Template with the edit question button**

```
<a href="{% url 'edit' question.pk %}">
```

**Edit:**

```
context = {
    'filtered_questions': filtered_questions,
    'username':username,
}
```

Tried to pass username in as context variable and render it in template like so

```
 <a href="{% url 'edit' username question.pk %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give username too for `url` to match:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit' username=user.username pk=question.pk %}">
```

You don't have to pass `username` from context if you are passing `request.user.username`. Coz, `user` is always accessible from authenticated page from template.

Comment: Even after adding the username the error message persists. Do I need to pass this username variable through the context?

Comment: Yes... pass the username from context and place it before ``question.pk``

Comment: Okay, thank you that helped! However, I am still confused about how I am supposed to get the correct question.pk. If i cannot access this until the edit_post view how am I supposed to pass this to my template in "dashboard"?

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what you are asking. Please explain a bit.

Comment: I am trying to access the "question.pk" in my dashboard template, but I do not pass in the question context variable until an item is clicked which triggers edit_post.

Comment: pass question in the context then access it

Comment: So im passing it in to the edit_post like this 'question = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)' because I want the edit_post method to recognize which question has been clicked. But in my dashboard view how am I supposed to know which question has been clicked? Sorry, very confused by this. thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221520/discussion-between-biplove-lamichhane-and-clayton-horning).